# how i make File.js (java script file) execute and loaded in a specific page and not loaded in other pages?

Tags: javascript

How to make java script like that loaded only in homepage and no loaded in other categories , post pages as they'have no slider .. so i no need it !

`<script src='http://slideshow.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>`

Comment: you have to be more specific in the way the home page is distinguished from others. Are you using server side PHP, .Net...?

Comment: Yeah, this is not a JavaScript problem. This is server-side problem. If you are somewhat restricted in modyfing server-side, then there is nothing you can do. If you are not, then you have to write a PHP/.NET/Python/Perl/Ruby/whatever/batman/watman script which will take care of this. Probably you will use some fancy templating system.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the script to load on a page, then don't include it.  If you're using a CMS for your site, then post the CMS that you're using so we can help you.

If all that fails, you can set up something like an ID on your `body` tag.  Then you can test the ID of the body, if it passes, execute the code, if it fails, then don't execute it.

**--EDIT--**

An example would be something like this..

```
<body id="home">
   <script language="JavaScript">
       function init() {
           if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].id == 'home') {
               // We're grabbing the head and the script
               var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                   scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

               // We're setting the new script element to use the URL of the script we want
               scriptElement.type= 'text/javascript';
               scriptElement.src= 'http://slideshow.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui.min.js';

               // We're adding this newly created element to the head
               headElement.appendChild(scriptElement);
           }
       }
       init();
   </script>
...
</body>
```

Try something like that.  For a greater explanation for using dynamic JavaScript elements, check out this page: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to make id to body and attatch it with this js ?
i use blogger !

Comment: It's pretty simple to make an ID on a body.  Just do it like this: `<body id="home">`  That's all you have to do.  I'll edit my answer to give an example function.  But I'm a bit wary to do so.  I'd rather have you understand what you're doing, and work out the solution on your own, than have me write you a solution, and you not get why it works.

Comment: i attach it like that ??

<body id="home"><script src='http://slideshow.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></body>

??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to controll this behaviour on the client side I would try this approach:

```
<script>location.pathname == '/' && document.write('<script src="http://slideshow.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

But of course better to let you CMS/server code handle it for you. But based on the information you provided I can only give you client-side solution.

Comment: XML: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do something wrong, if you don't need script, just don't load it as Tim answered.

Anyway possible workaround, you can create script `yousrcipt.js`, include it in every page. In this script you can write something similar to this

```
if (window.location == 'whateverhomepage')  {
   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'http://slideshow.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui.min.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```